# Error while trying to compile directory with .scss files

Tags: sass

I simply want to compile the whole directory with .scss files like it is in docs but I get an error, what am I doing wrong?

The command is: `sass scss:public/main.css` but I get this error:

> Errno: EISDIR: Is a directory @ rb_sysopen scss Use --trace for backtrace

Answer (score 4):

The Sass documentation shows no such usage for compiling with the `sass` command.  You cannot compile a directory to a single file.

> You can also tell Sass to watch the file and update the CSS every time
>   the Sass file changes:
>
> ```
> sass --watch input.scss:output.css
> ```
>
> If you have a directory with many Sass files, you can also tell Sass
>   to watch the entire directory:
>
> ```
> sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets
> ```

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass

Comment: so how can I compile many scss files (for example from Bootstrap) into one file to include it on my web page?

Comment: should I create one file with @import directives ?

Comment: That's what's intended, yes.